# iAds fail to appear when app is installed from App Store

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iad

I recently released my free app SchoolTool w/ ads into the store. I did all the proper testing beforehand to make sure iAds were working. However, once the app was approved and I installed it, the iAds failed to load. Anyone have a similar experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same experience. After a couple of days of it not working, I emailed Apple to ask what was up with my app. A day or so later, my iAds started showing.